# Semi Circle in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I need to draw a semicircle in android studio XML file. I want that semicircle to be responsive.
I tried drawing an oval shape and then setting margins to it. But its not responsive.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="440dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already integrated circular sector in your layout, you need to just add a negative margin to view. And also please view in FrameLayout so you can overlap your remaining image with another layout. I think this will solve your problem.

## {< Codelord >}